# jQuery fadeIn() not working with AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Here's my HTML code:

```
<div id="loading"><img src="blah blah" alt="Loading..." /></div>
```

Here's my JS code:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {       
            $('#loading').hide();

            $("#submitSessionBtn").click(function () {
                $('#loading').fadeIn();                         
                d3.select("svg").remove();

                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "Home/GetStuff/",
                    dataType: "json",
                    async: false,
                    success: function (result) {
                        console.log("Success!");
                        $('#loading').fadeOut();})
```

The image is basically a spinner image indicating loading. I want the image to be displayed as soon as I click the submit button and disappear when the AJAX call is done. But, currently it shows up a few seconds before the AJAX call completes and not as soon as the submit button is pressed.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can u try using $("#submitSessionBtn").on('click',funciton(){.....});

Comment: do $('#loading').hide(); work ?

Comment: @shushanthp That does not change anything.

Comment: I don't get what the problem is exactly. I mean fadeIn and fadeOut have delay. Maybe just go for hide() and show()?

Comment: use 'show()' instead of 'fadeIn()' for a faster effect.

Comment: I think default delay is 400ms for fadeIn or fadeOut,

Comment: Generally doing ajax calls is pretty darn fast in todays browser, and especially when developing on a local computer I would think you wouldn't even see the spinner as it won't have time to fade in. It seems strange that it would show up several seconds later when the fading in starts immediately when the button is clicked, and the image should be completely faded in ~0.5 seconds, if it's not removed by the fadeOut before that.

Comment: I tried show/hide and now the image does not even show up :(

Comment: @Bugaboo It probably does, but it's so fast you don't even notice.

Comment: I know it does not since I don't see the result of my AJAX call. The output of this submit button is a graph and I can see it not being computed during the time the GIF file is not showing up. With the show/hide, I don't even see the GIF file show up (seconds before or otherwise)

Comment: @Bugaboo Ok, but is the AJAX call successful?

Comment: It is. When I use hide/show, the GIF never shows up. The call succeeds and the graph showsu p. When I use fadein/fadeout, the AJAZ call succeeds and the GIF shows up a few seconds before the output graph shows up (not as soon as I hti the submit button).

Comment: Ok, so both ways the AJAX call is successful right? Either you use show/hide or fadin/fadout? I am confused, it should not matter what you use the call should be successful anyway.\

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80831/discussion-between-bugaboo-and-mikey).

Answer (score 1):

The fadeIn function behaves asynchronously and the code you have immediately below the call will continue to execute before the fadeIn operation is complete.  What you want to do is not run your code until it's complete. To do this, the fadeIn function (as with show, slideDown, etc) takes a function as an optional parameter that it will execute when the operation is complete.  Put your ajax call inside of an anonymous function that you pass to fadeIn.  It would look like this:

```
$('#loading').fadeIn(function(){
     $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "Home/GetStuff/",
                    dataType: "json",
                    async: false,
                    success: function (result) {
                        console.log("Success!");
                        $('#loading').fadeOut();})
});
```

Comment: But if you don't care about the fade effect, you'd be better off just setting the display style to block and then back to hidden.  That way you won't have the async issues.  $('#loading').style('display', 'block') and $('#loading').style('display', 'hidden')

Answer (score 0):

You do have the $(#loading') tags in the correct positions because only once the ajax call is complete will success be called. I would recommend using just show and hide. I'm sure FadeIn is introducing some gradient color between sequences so it is showing up just can't see it yet. As for disappearing to early that's because some execution is occurring. From my experience it was normal if doing database fetch or some text file reading that maybe a clean up occurred behind the scenes.

Comment: When I use show/hide, the image (the gif file) does not even show up. My problem is it not disappearing too early but the fact that it starts showing up so late. I would expect the GIF to show up *as soon as* I hit the submit button and then disappear when the AJAX call succeeds.

Comment: Make sure this GIF you're attempting to show is hosted from your machine and you aren't grabbing it from a server. This will create that timing issue. This happened to me when i pulled jspin from url..